# how to get current logged-in user details in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel

how do i get current logged in user details in laravel 5.2 ? I have done something to get the user name but it doesn't work properly. 
Here is the code that gets the current logged-in user name

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{

 /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    public function current_user()
    {


        if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->name) {

            return 'hello';
            return user()->name;
        }

    }
}
```

Here If i just return a ** return 'Hello'** in the function current_user , it works fine after checking the if condition, so i see there is no problem with if condition. But when i return **user()->name** it says 
**Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\user()**

Comment: I've voted to close this question as the answers below are the solution however it is a simple typographical issue so the question will be of no use the future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

To access authorized user information use `\Auth::user()`. You probably just missing `\Auth::` part, because You using correct syntax in condition.

Comment: yea and he has 2 returns i guess!

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja As I understand, OP putted first return intentionally just for checking if that part of the code is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code a little bit.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{

 /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    public function current_user()
    {
        if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->name) {
            return 'Hello '.\Auth::user()->name; //this line changed
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can get the `current user name`.

You want to return 2 values, that's not possible. When you return something your method will stop running. So that's why you didn't get the user name.

Hope this works!